# Having trouble with WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my game give the player a powerup when it collides with the powerup.  The powerup functions correctly, but when it reaches the yield WaitForSeconds statement, nothing after it is executed, resulting in the player having the powerup forever instead of a  set amount of time.  Why is the code after it not executing and how can i fix it?

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D( Collision2D collision ){
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        if(isActive){
            isActive = false;
            gameObject.renderer.enabled = false;
            StartCoroutine( activatePowerup( collision.gameObject ) );

        }else;
        Debug.Log ("Hit player");

    }else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}

public IEnumerator activatePowerup( GameObject player ){
    player.GetComponent<Player>().setAttackDelaySeconds (0.25f);
    Debug.Log ("Powerup Activated");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);  
    Debug.Log ("Finisehd waiting");
    deactivatePowerup ( player );

}

public void deactivatePowerup( GameObject player ){
    player.GetComponent<Player> ().setAttackDelaySeconds (0.75f);
    Debug.Log ("Powerup Finished");
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.  Since the powerup would hit the ground after it was activated on the player, it would destroy the object before deactivating the powerup, so it would never deactivate.  This was fixed by changing...

```
    }else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

to

```
    }else if (isActive && collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```